# React Material UI(Table): Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I use Material Table's action function and when you click it, a dialog will be shown.
however, when I write a TextField inside the Dialog, this problem occured.

```
jspdf.min.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at B (jspdf.min.js:37)
    at t (jspdf.min.js:37)
    at V (jspdf.min.js:37)
```

What will be the cause?
It is possible to use TextField inside the Dialog(with Material Table)?
Thanks:)

Comment: Can you show the codes or upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: It is possible to show a dialog, but we need to see some of your code pls.